# Simple MySQL query won't work

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm trying to run this simple php script from browser but it won't work. It seems that it connects to database but can't complete mysql query. Anyway this query works fine from PhpMyAdmin. What seems to be a problem?

```
<?php
// DB
$DB_HOSTNAME = "localhost";
$DB_USERNAME = "********";
$DB_PASSWORD = "********";
$DB_DATABASE = "vladbl0m_eshop";

// Create connection
$con=mysqli_connect($DB_HOSTNAME, $DB_USERNAME, $DB_PASSWORD, $DB_DATABASE); 

// Check connection
 if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))   {
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL:" . mysqli_connect_error();   
 }
else echo "CONNECTED TO " . $DB_DATABASE;

// mySQL query

// execute the query.
$result = $link->query("INSERT INTO oc_test SET text ='12345'") or die("Error in the consult.." . mysqli_error($link));

?>
```

Comment: When debugging, always set error_reporting to the max.  When asking here, always include the actual errors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no `$link` defined anywhere... use `$con` instead of that.

Replace the `$link` with `$con` and see what you are doing it wrong , since you mapped the connection wrongly , you are not able to see the proper errors.

Comment: UPDATE and INSERT were mixed

Comment: `Insert into table set col='someval'` is a valid statement  for inserting records.

Comment: That form of INSERT syntax is valid in MySQL, but FWIW it's not standard SQL.

Comment: Lol, thats my fault! Thank you!

Comment: @BillKarwin, Thanks for that valuable information !